# how to work out payload size from html5 websocket

Tags: java, html, websocket, byte, payload

how can I tell an html5 message payload length over websockets?

Im aware the base protocol consists of an op code, then length is determine by the next 1 to 8 bytes, then the following values is the hashing and then the rest is payload!

Im creating a java serverside application that will receivea message from a html5 client and then handle, iI can handle messages up to 256 bytes.

Any help to work this out even manually would be great (i.e how to habdle the bytes that determine the payload)

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three ways how the payload length of a websocket frame can be encoded, which depend on the length of the payload:

1. 125 or less
2. 126-65535
3. 65536 +

Which way is used can be told by looking at the value of the 7 last bits of the 2nd byte (the first bit of the 2nd byte is the masking flag).

When it's below 126, it's the payload length.
When it's 126, the payload length is in the following two bytes.
When it's 127, the payload length is in the following 8 bytes.

So the algorithm you have to follow to interpret a websocket frame is:

0. read the 1st byte ("`byte0`") to get the fin flag and the opcode
1. read the 2nd byte ("`byte1`")
2. when `byte1` is greater than 127, subtract 127 from `byte1` and set `masked` to `true`
3. when `byte1` is now 126, read the next two bytes and convert it to a `short`. This is the `payload_length`.
4. when `byte1` is 127, read the next eight bytes and convert it to a `long`. This is the `payload_length`.
5. when `byte1` is something else, the `payload_length` is equal to the value of `byte1`
6. when `masked` is true, read the next 4 byte. This is the `masking_key`.
7. read the number of bytes you have in the `payload_length` to get the payload.
8. when `masked` is true, apply the `masking_key` to the payload.

There is no hash-code in a websocket frame, you must have mixed something up. The integrity of a websocket frame is ensured by the TCP layer beneath it.

For more information about the Websocket protocol, refer to the [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

Comment: Yes sorry meant masking key, not hashing

Comment: @OwainFormby When my answer helps you, please accept it (the tick-icon next to it). When it doesn't please tell me what you don't understand.

Comment: Not sure how Java handles the data structs, but it's worth pointing out that it's **BIG endian** you're working with.. So when reading the 2 or 8 bytes that indicates the payload length, you got to intemperate it as big endian. Else you're screwed.