# When I send 127+ characters from chrome websocket, my golang server cannot see more than 126

Tags: google-chrome, go, websocket

I'm having a blast reinventing the wheel and playing with bits to implement a simple server. It's almost functional, but I'm not sure if this issue is my client or my server. Here is the function where I pass the resulting byte array from net.Conn Read

```
func readWsFrame(p []byte) {
    // process first byte
    b := p[0]
    fmt.Printf("first byte: %b\n", b)
    fin := b & 128 // hopefully 128, for fin
    op := b & 15   // hopefully 1, for text
    fmt.Printf("fin: %d\nop: %d\n", fin, op)
    // process second byte
    b = p[1]
    fmt.Printf("second byte: %b\n", b)
    masked := b & 128 // whether or not the payload is masked
    length := b & 127 // payload length
    fmt.Printf("masked: %d\nlength: %d\n", masked, length)
    // process bytes 3-7 (masking key)
    key := p[2:6]
    // payload
    d := p[6:]
    if length == 126 {
        key = p[4:8]
        d = p[8:]
        fmt.Println("med key")
    } else if length == 127 {
        key = p[10:14]
        d = p[14:]
        fmt.Println("big key")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("lil key")
    }
    fmt.Printf("masking key: %b\n", key)
    fmt.Printf("masked data: %b\n", d)
    var decoded []byte
    for index := 0; index < int(length); index++ {
        decoded = append(decoded, d[index]^key[index%4])
    }
    fmt.Printf("unmasked data: %b\n", decoded)
    payload := string(decoded)
    fmt.Println("payload: ", payload)
}
```

The client code is me having the dev console open right off this web page and running

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:16163");
ws.send("a".repeat(125))
ws.send("a".repeat(126))
ws.send("a".repeat(127))
ws.send("a".repeat(400))
```

My server is doing what I expect until I reach 127 characters. At that point, and every amount over 126, my 2nd byte is 11111110 and the length is 126. I can see the unmasked/encoded/magic message doesn't go beyond 126 a's.

I'm sure my go code is sub-par and there might be something obvious here, but I'm looking at the bits themselves, and I can see a 0 where I am expecting a 1, please help me, thank you!

I saw a similar question about writing messages larger than 126 bytes and how I'll need extra bytes for payload size, but in this case my client is the chrome web browser.

--edit:

I realize that I will never see more than 126 characters based on the loop I have there, but I should still see a 1 in the final bit in the second byte for these larger messages, right?

--edit:

Came across this [how to work out payload size from html5 websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271598/how-to-work-out-payload-size-from-html5-websocket)

I guess I misunderstood everything else I was searching for. Can someone confirm this? If the length is <126, the length is byte & 127. If the length is 126, the length is the value of the next 2 bytes. If the length is 127, the length is the next 4 bytes.

I thought initially that the length would be 127 if it payload length was 127+ hah, oops. So when the length is 126 or 127, the 2nd byte is not part of the actual length? I'll probably confirm all of this with testing, but I thank you all for resolving this issue before the weekend so I can finish this side project.

Comment: You aren't updating the `length` property after realizing it's `127` or `126`... which means you aren't reading the `length` data in the bytes that follow the initial length indicator.

Comment: Shouldn't byte & 127 catch whether the length is <126, 126 or 127? I know I need to read the next bytes when the length is 126 and 127 (see the key and data indices moved up), but I'm asking why the last bit in the 2nd byte is always 0.  Oh wait.. if it's 126, would the 127th character be part of the length in the next 2 bytes!? I feel silly for reading that, but that seems very... not intuitive. So I should only expect the 127 bit if the payload is greater than 65k?

Comment: I think you're thinking about the first byte slightly different than I would suggest. This isn't a question of length, it's a question of encoding. If the length is encoded using 64bits (8 bytes), than the length indicator == 127. If the length is encoded in 2 bytes, the indicator == 126, if the length fits in 7 bits, the indicator byte includes the length... For example, the length 60 can be encoded in all three ways (albeit, some use more space). There's a [C Websocket implementation here](goo.gl/5tSFa9) if you want to read an example decoding of the length.

Comment: So that byte is a length indicator unless the length is small enough to fit in that length... interesting. I'd accept your comment as an answer if I could, thanks.

Comment: I'm happy I could help. I posted the information as an answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: Accepted, thanks again. Now that I have a server, I can use it for something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should update the length property after realizing it's 127 or 126 by reading the length data in the bytes that follow the initial length indicator.

I would consider those 7 "length" bits slightly differently. They don't really indicate length as much as they indicate encoding.

If the length is encoded using 64bits (8 bytes), than the length indicator == 127.

If the length is encoded in 2 bytes, than the indicator == 126.

Otherwise, the length is encoded in the 7 bits of the indicator itself.

For example, the length 60 can be encoded in all three ways (albeit, some use more space).

There's a [C Websocket implementation here](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/721236f6175aa578f73437b480b249763484eedc/src/http/websockets.c#L242-L287) if you want to read an example decoding of the length.

Good Luck!