# Understanding this websocket frame parsing code

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, binary, bit-manipulation

Beginner here trying to understand on a low-level how websockets work. I am trying to create my own implementation, however I am very confused on the logic of parsing the data frame that get's sent from client => server.

I know the buffer that is received on the server side consists of multiple bytes, with the first two being the main header information (fin bit, length, opcode, mask, etc).

I found the following code on SO that parses both the bytes, and from testing, it DOES indeed return the correct values.

```
let index = 0;
frame = {
    data: new Buffer(0),
    fin: (buffer[index] & 128) === 128,
    length: buffer[index + 1] & 127,
    masked: (buffer[index + 1] & 128) === 128,
    opcode: buffer[index] & 15
}
```

What my main question is though.... HOW exactly is this returning the correct values?

I know buffer[index] and buffer[index+1] are referring to the first and second byte, and the AND operand is being used to compare the binary values of each, and output 1 whenever both indexes in both numbers equal to 1, otherwise 0...... but...

Where do the numbers after the & operator come from? ex: opcode is 15, length is 127.

HOW exactly does using the AND operator on both these values, give the right result? This is what I really don't understand.

I apologize if this is basic computer science concepts that I'm not understanding, but if anyone out there is able to explain to me what exactly is occurring with this code, it would be so much appreciated.

Comment: A bitwise `&` returns the overlap of the bit-sequences of the two numbers. If you reduce the value on one side down to a single bit, you can "test" with that value wether that bit is set in the other number. That's what the `128` does. It checks the MSB of the byte. The `15` == last 4 bits and `127` == last 7 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I get that it looks like a normal AND comparison but rather it is a boolean AND comparison being made.

To clarify a bit more specific, buffer[index] & 15  for opcode says compare buffer[index] as a binary number with 15(this is the highest allowed opcode for websockets) as a binary number bit by bit and return the binary results as an integer, the opcode itself tells which frame type is being sent.(If you are curious you can deep dive on this here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11.8.)

On the length part of 127 I refer to this answer on SO since it is a solid answer: [how to work out payload size from html5 websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271598/how-to-work-out-payload-size-from-html5-websocket/18282479#18282479)

For further reading on the operator see the section in my source on bitwise logical operators.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators